# bootstrap justify-content-center doesn't work with row flex

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have a container, I want to center align all the contents inside the row class, but When I provide justify-content-center, It doesn't have any effect on my div, does justify-content works on row ?

```
    <div class="container my-5">
   <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <hr class="col-4  border-2 border-top border-danger">
    <p class="col-4" >Skills and Abilities</p>
    <hr class="col-4  border-2 border-top border-danger">
   </div>
    </div>
```

any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: If you want to set the text of `Skills and Abilities`  in the horizontally center then simply give the `text-align: center;` to the row and check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should use div tags intended of hr tags. But as per your code just add text-center class in p tag.

```
 <div class="container my-5">
  <div class="row jusitfy-content-center">
    <hr class="col-4 border-2 mt-2 border-top border-danger" />
    <p class="col-4 text-center">Skills and Abilities</p>
    <hr class="col-4 border-2 mt-2 border-top border-danger" />
  </div>
</div>
```

[This is the final output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5OrIO.png)

And if you want to achieve the above result. Then your approach is not recommend, you can try this:

```
 <div class="position-relative">
  <hr class="border border-danger" />
  <p class="position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle bg-white fw-bold 
    text-black-50 px-4">
    Skills and Abilities
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your Answer is Mind Blowing! Thanks my dear.

Comment: This will work as long as your background color is white. But if you have an image behind it you will get an unsightly white box around the text. Instead, you can make it a real border. Check this one out: https://www.trysmudford.com/blog/css-header-legend/

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 <div class="container row my-5">
   <div class="d-flex justify-content-center">
     <hr class="col-4  border-2 border-top border-danger" />
     <p class="col-4" >Skills and Abilities</p>
     <hr class="col-4  border-2 border-top border-danger" />
   </div>
 </div>
```

If still not work try to change

```
<hr class="col-4  border-2 border-top border-danger" />
```

to

```
<div class="col-4  border-2 border-top border-danger" />
```

Comment: I tried all you mentioned, none of them works. in fact div element with no closing tag is semantically wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use either Flexbox or CSS Grid for this. It will be more flexible than adding a colored box behind the text.

Here's the HTML:

```
<h2>Title</h2>
<h2>Title number two</h2>
<h2>Aenean lacinia bibendum nulla sed consectetur. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum. Curabitur blandit tempus porttitor. Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</h2>

/* Sample CSS */
body {
    background: linear-gradient(#A0BAF7, #4CACC1);
    min-height: 100vh;
}
h2 {
    margin: 30px 0;
    font: 700 2em/1.4 'Avenir', sans-serif;
    color: #FFF;
}
```

Here's the Flexbox solution: https://codepen.io/trys/pen/vjRXLW/

```
h2 {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
}
h2:before,
h2:after {
    content: '';
    border-top: 2px solid;
    margin: 0 20px 0 0;
    flex: 1 0 20px;
}
h2:after {
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}
```

And here the CSS Grid solution: https://codepen.io/trys/pen/vjRzPa

```
h2 {
    display: grid;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    text-align: center;
    grid-template-columns: minmax(20px, 1fr) auto minmax(20px, 1fr);
    grid-gap: 20px;
}
h2:before,
h2:after {
    content: '';
    border-top: 2px solid;
}
```

Comment: This would also work great, but It doesn't use bootstrap, that's why I think the top one is easier. Thnx a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Simply add `d-flex` to your container

Link Flex Boostrap : https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/flex/

```
<div class="container my-5">
   <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <hr class="col-4  border-2 border-top border-danger">
    <p class="col-4" >Skills and Abilities</p>
    <hr class="col-4  border-2 border-top border-danger">
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I have tried that. I use bootstrap version 5.

Comment: Flex does not change with bootstrap version 5. Try to reproduce your code.

Comment: I tried that one, all the ones bootstrap mentioned, but it doesn't work.